# UIScrollView always bounces back to the bottom of the previous one

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, scrollview

I am using `UItableView` that list all titles of movie, and then I selected on title in cell list; it navigated to new `UIViewController` to show the detail of that story. **I have scrolled down down to read all.** And then click back button without scrolling up.

I selected another title to see the story but my content is hide because my scroll view is bounces back to the bottom. its seem like it remember the previous one I have scrolled.
even though I'm trying to scroll up but it still hide little bit my top content.

Can anyone help me please.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use singleton class or Appdelegete class to remember the previous index  of your table view . When you come back from the story controller . Just do scroll to that index when table is loaded again with the data .

```
[[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:previousIndex atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
```

Comment: I'm very new. Can you tell me how to remember the previous index of table view? and where to put it? Thank thank

Comment: create the property in app delegate called previousIndex , when you go to the next view . set delegate.previousIndex=yourIndex and get it again when you come back